# Is it a breach of etiquette to ask a French company if they've received my job application?

Tags: employment

I am an Australian citizen trying to move to France. I found a job advertised on the weekend that has visa sponsorship for overseas applicants (very rare, the only one I've seen so far). The job is at a large international company with its headquarters in France. I sent the application four days ago but due to the weekend they would only have had a day to look at it so far, assuming it reached them. It is currently Tuesday afternoon in Australia but still early morning in France.

I didn't apply directly to the company but on a recruitment site so I don't know how efficient that process is. Would it look bad if I contacted the company directly to ask about my application or would that be a positive because I am eager? I have no experience with French companies yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea whether it's a breach of “etiquette” but I don't think it matters much either way.

But to manage your expectations, I have had the occasion to apply for jobs in several European countries and French companies are clearly the ones that treat applicants the most casually. I never received any acknowledgment that my application was received and they also mostly do not bother contacting you if they have no interest, even if you had an interview!

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate about the recruitment site? Did you apply to the company directly, or through a recruiting agency?

In the first case, if the company has already received your CV, wait for one or two more days. It's common for a French company to wait for a week before calling back a candidate (if they ever do so), so if you contact them now, the recruiter may not have checked your CV yet. It's ok to follow up an application, but sending it too early may look bad for you.

If you applied to a recruiting agency, which is supposed to transfer your application to the company, then, without any news from them, you can assume that the company hasn't heard from you yet. You can apply directly to the company in that case, to speed up the process.

Comment: It was a site such as seek.com.au (but with overseas postings), which allows companies to place ads on it. It was not the company's own, internal careers page which I actually found after I had applied through the other site. There was no mention of an agency so I am assuming it is direct to the employer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In that case, wait for one or two more days before sending an email. If you haven't done it already, it could be an occasion to write a cover letter (it always shows motivation).